# SSIS "Enumerator failed to retrieve element at index" Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my SSIS package I am using a data flow task to extract data from SQL Server and put it into a dataset with the following schema:

```
Column1 Int32
Column2 Object
Column3 Object
Column4 String
Column5 Double
```

That step seems to work well. In the foreach editor I mapped the columns to variables like this:

```
VARIABLE      | INDEX
User::Column1 | 0
User::Column2 | 1
User::Column3 | 2
User::Column4 | 3
User::Column5 | 4
```

When I run the package I get the following error on the foreach task:

```
Error: The enumerator failed to retrieve element at index "4".
Error: ForEach Variable Mapping number 5 to variable "User::Column5" cannot be applied.
```

There are no null values in Column5 and I can clearly see all 5 columns in the query when I run it against the database. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if the origin of your Column4 String is of VARCHAR(MAX) type then you need to use Object data type not String for that.  That is the most common issue that creates that type of error.

Comment: The data types in SQL Server for the data are INT, INT, INT, VARCHAR(10), MONEY.

Comment: If your Query is Int, Int, Int, Varchar(10), Money, is there a reason why your variables are Int32, Object, Object, String, Double and not Int32, Int32, Int32, String, Double?

Comment: Column2 and Column3 were set as Object instead of Int32 because of potential null values in the data.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the problem. The target dataset in the data flow task was dropping the last column for some reason. Once I recreated the dataset destination everything worked.